# Access list with SNMP v3 Cisco

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, snmp, access-control

I was wondering if someone could help me with something. I am trying to set up SNMP v3 but with access control. Now, I have made the user and group. That's all fine, but I can't seem to get the access control part working.

When I attempt to add it at the end the switch throws a paddy saying it's not possible.

Here is what I am putting in:
`snmp-server user User1 Group1 v3 auth md5 BeepBoop access 10`

The access list I am trying to make is `10`. I have made the list with the IP addresses within the list.

edit:

```
snmp-server user User1 Group1 v3 auth md5 BeepBoop access 10
                                                   ^
ERROR: % Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
```

Cisco Adaptive Security Appliance Software Version 9.8(1) Firepower Extensible Operating System Version 2.2(1.47) Device Manager Version 7.8(1)

Comment: You need to give the exact message you are getting.

Comment: @RonMaupin I have just added it.

Comment: OK. Also, what is you IOS version (`sh version`)?

Comment: Cisco Adaptive Security Appliance Software Version 9.8(1)
Firepower Extensible Operating System Version 2.2(1.47)
Device Manager Version 7.8(1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have the `access` option on the ASA `snmp-server user` command like you do on IOS.

> **snmp-server user** *username* *group-name* { **v3** [ **encrypted** ]] [ **auth** { **md5** | **sha** ]} *auth-password* [ **priv** [
>   **des** | **3des** | **aes** ] [ **128** | **192** | **256** ] priv-password

As Ricky Beam points out, you use the `snmp-server host` command to restict the host access:

> **snmp-server host** interface { hostname | ip_address } [ **trap** | **poll** ] [ **community** community-string ] [ **version** { **1** | **2c** | 3 username }] [ **udp-port** port ]

See the [*Cisco ASA Series CLI Configuration Guide, 9.0*](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa90/configuration/guide/asa_90_cli_config/monitor_snmp.html#48140):

> [image]

Comment: *snmp-server host ...* is where access is restricted. (cisco urls rarely stay static.)